# Do PFAM entries differ in species? If yes, which PFAM entries are statistically different in which animal specie?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, biostatistics

I would like to perform a statistical test for each row (protein name) of each animal species to see which protein name is statistically different from others in each animal species.

Which statistical test should I apply to see differences in PFAM entries and to see which PFAM entry is statistically different in which species?

Using the R `dput` function as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/49994249/6828329), my data is the following:

```
structure(list(PFAM = structure(c(412L, 297L, 330L, 404L, 397L, 
65L), .Label = c("2-Hacid_dh_C", "5_nucleotid_C", "6PGD", "7tm_1", 
"7tm_2", "7tm_3", "7tm_6", "7tm_7", "7TM_GPCR_Srw", "A_deaminase", 
"A2M_comp", "AA_permease", "AA_permease_2", "Aa_trans", "AAA", 
"AAA_12", "ABC_membrane", "ABC_tran", "ABC2_membrane", "Abhydro_lipase", 
"Abhydrolase_1", "Acatn", "Acetyltransf_1", "Actin", "Acyl_transf_1", 
"Acyl_transf_3", "Acyl-CoA_dh_1", "Acyltransferase", "Adaptin_N", 
"adh_short", "adh_short_C2", "ADK", "AIP3", "Aldedh", "Aldo_ket_red", 
"Alk_phosphatase", "Alpha-amylase", "Amidase", "Amidase_2", "Amino_oxidase", 
"Aminotran_1_2", "AMP-binding", "An_peroxidase", "ANAPC4_WD40", 
"ANF_receptor", "Ank_2", "Ank_4", "Ank_5", "Annexin", "Anoctamin", 
"ANTH", "Arf", "ArfGap", "Arm", "Arrestin_N", "ASC", "Astacin", 
"ATP-synt_E", "Band_7", "Bax1-I", "Beach", "BIR", "BK_channel_a", 
"Bromodomain", "BTB", "bZIP_1", "bZIP_2", "C2", "Cadherin", "CAP", 
"CAP_GLY", "Carb_anhydrase", "Catalase", "Cation_ATPase_C", "Cation_efflux", 
"CBFD_NFYB_HMF", "CBM_14", "CD36", "CDP-OH_P_transf", "CH", "Chitin_bind_4", 
"Choline_transpo", "Chromo", "Chromo_shadow", "CK_II_beta", "CLASP_N", 
"CN_hydrolase", "cNMP_binding", "COesterase", "Collagen", "Complex1_LYR", 
"Cpn60_TCP1", "CRAL_TRIO", "Cu-oxidase_3", "CUB", "Cupin_8", 
"Cyclin_N", "Cyt-b5", "DAGK_acc", "DAO", "DUF1907", "DUF229", 
"DUF243", "DUF3421", "DUF3504", "E1_DerP2_DerF2", "E1_dh", "E1-E2_ATPase", 
"EamA", "EB", "ECH_1", "EcKinase", "EF-hand_1", "EF-hand_6", 
"EF-hand_7", "EGF", "EGF_CA", "Elf1", "ELO", "Endonuclease_NS", 
"ERAP1_C", "ERM", "Ets", "Exo_endo_phos", "F-box", "F-box-like", 
"FA_desaturase", "FA_hydroxylase", "Far-17a_AIG1", "Fasciclin", 
"FH2", "FHA", "Fibrinogen_C", "Filamin", "FKBP_C", "fn3", "Forkhead", 
"Fringe", "FYVE", "G_glu_transpept", "G-alpha", "G-patch", "Galactosyl_T", 
"GATA", "GDP_Man_Dehyd", "GDPD", "GILT", "Glyco_hydro_1", "Glyco_hydro_18", 
"Glyco_hydro_20", "Glyco_hydro_31", "Glyco_transf_10", "Glyco_transf_22", 
"Glyco_transf_49", "Glycos_transf_2", "GMC_oxred_N", "GNT-I", 
"GRP", "GST_C_3", "GST_N_3", "GTP_EFTU", "Guanylate_cyc", "Guanylate_kin", 
"HA2", "HAD_2", "HEAT", "HECT", "Helicase_C", "Hemocyanin_C", 
"His_Phos_2", "Hist_deacetyl", "Histone", "HLH", "HlyIII", "HMG_box", 
"Homeobox", "Hormone_recep", "HSP20", "HSP70", "HTH_psq", "I-set", 
"IBN_N", "IBR", "ig", "Ig_2", "Ig_3", "Innexin", "Inositol_P", 
"Ion_trans", "Ion_trans_2", "IPK", "IQ", "JHBP", "JmjC", "Kazal_1", 
"Kazal_2", "Kelch_1", "KH_1", "Kinesin", "Kunitz_BPTI", "La", 
"Laminin_EGF", "Laminin_G_2", "Ldh_1_C", "Ldh_1_N", "Ldl_recept_a", 
"Lectin_C", "Lig_chan", "Lig_chan-Glu_bd", "LIM", "Lipase", "Lipocalin", 
"LRR_4", "LRR_6", "LRR_8", "LRR_9", "LSM", "Mab-21", "MADF_DNA_bdg", 
"MARVEL", "MBOAT", "MBT", "MCM", "Metallophos", "Methyltransf_25", 
"MFS_1", "MFS_1_like", "MH2", "MIF4G", "MIP", "Mito_carr", "MMR_HSR1", 
"MORN", "MOZ_SAS", "Mpv17_PMP22", "MRJP", "Myb_DNA-bind_5", "Myb_DNA-binding", 
"Myosin_head", "Myotub-related", "Na_Ca_ex", "Na_H_Exchanger", 
"NAD_binding_4", "NAD_kinase", "NAP", "Neur_chan_LBD", "Neur_chan_memb", 
"NHL", "NIF", "Ninjurin", "Nucleoside_tran", "NUDIX", "OATP", 
"OS-D", "Otopetrin", "OTU", "p450", "P4Ha_N", "PAP_assoc", "PAP2", 
"PARP", "PAS_11", "PAS_3", "PAX", "PBP_GOBP", "PCI", "PCMT", 
"PDEase_I", "PDZ", "Peptidase_C1", "Peptidase_C14", "Peptidase_C2", 
"Peptidase_C48", "Peptidase_C78", "Peptidase_C97", "Peptidase_M1", 
"Peptidase_M10", "Peptidase_M13_N", "Peptidase_M14", "Peptidase_M17", 
"Peptidase_M19", "Peptidase_M2", "Peptidase_M28", "Peptidase_S10", 
"Peptidase_S28", "PfkB", "PH", "PHD", "PhoLip_ATPase_C", "Phospholip_A2_2", 
"PI3_PI4_kinase", "PID", "PIF1", "PIP5K", "Piwi", "PKD_channel", 
"Pkinase", "Pkinase_Tyr", "PNP_UDP_1", "polyprenyl_synt", "Pou", 
"PP2C", "PQ-loop", "Pribosyl_synth", "Pro_isomerase", "Proteasome", 
"PTR2", "PWWP", "PX", "Pyr_redox_2", "Pyridoxal_deC", "QVR", 
"RabGAP-TBC", "Rap_GAP", "Ras", "RasGAP", "RasGEF", "RCC1", "RGS", 
"RhoGAP", "RhoGEF", "Ribosomal_60s", "Ribosomal_L7Ae", "Ribosomal_S11", 
"Ribosomal_S5", "RINGv", "RIO1", "RNase_H", "RNase_T", "RRM_1", 
"RRM_5", "Sad1_UNC", "SAM_1", "SAM_2", "Sec1", "Sec63", "Sema", 
"Serpin", "SET", "SGL", "SH2", "SH3_1", "SH3_9", "Sina", "SIR2", 
"SMC_N", "SNF", "SNF2_N", "Snf7", "Spaetzle", "Spectrin", "SPRY", 
"SSF", "Sugar_tr", "Sulfatase", "Sulfate_transp", "Sulfotransfer_1", 
"Sulfotransfer_2", "Sushi", "SVWC", "Synaptobrevin", "T-box", 
"Tetraspannin", "TGF_beta", "THAP", "ThiF", "Thioredoxin", "TLD", 
"TPR_1", "TPR_12", "TPR_2", "TPT", "Transferrin", "TRAP_alpha", 
"Trehalase", "Trehalose_recp", "tRNA-synt_1", "Tropomyosin", 
"Troponin", "Trypsin", "TSP_1", "TTL", "Tubulin", "TUDOR", "ubiquitin", 
"UCH", "UDPGT", "Ufd2P_core", "UQ_con", "V_ATPase_I", "V-set", 
"Vinculin", "Vitellogenin_N", "VPS9", "VWC", "VWD", "WD40", "WH2", 
"wnt", "WW", "Y_phosphatase", "zf-AD", "zf-B_box", "zf-C2H2", 
"zf-C2H2_4", "zf-C2H2_jaz", "zf-C3HC4_3", "zf-C4", "zf-CCCH", 
"zf-CCHC", "zf-Di19", "zf-H2C2_2", "zf-HC5HC2H_2", "zf-LITAF-like", 
"zf-met", "zf-MYND", "zf-RING_2", "Zip", "Zona_pellucida"), class = "factor"), 
    A.glapripennis = c(93L, 161L, 100L, 147L, 116L, 46L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try copy your data using the `dput()` function (as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/q/49994249/6828329 ).

Comment: Can you also please add your specific question to the body of your post? At the moment, it is only in the title.

Comment: I see no question. Add it at the bottom of your post (below the data).

Comment: I added a question .